# Why is php_imagic extension removed from WampServer Version 2.0?

Tags: php, wampserver

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: why I don't know, but you can always add it if you want and need (I admit I am not currently aware of the exact procedure and where to get the working binaries... but since extensions are made to extend, they must be always "addable" _later_ someway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a reason.

The dll of imagick doesn't work with wamp 2.0 because wampserver is not compiled with VC9.

I seems you can resolve this by compiling yourself php5 and apache in VC9. I Didn't try.